# Permanent syntax on switch for Vim over OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, syntax-highlighting

I use the terminal to vim into existing and new programs. I hate the fact that at all times I need to kick in `:syntax on` on the command line to make the syntax all colorful. Does anyone have a recipe for how I can make sure my terminal always kicks in with colorful syntax ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put `syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

Add `syntax on` to your `~/.vimrc`.  See `:help initialization`.

Comment: @Randyboth of you got the correct answer, I flipped a coin and decided to award the one with lesser points a point  :)