# Any default settings possible for VIM editor?

Tags: vim

I use ":set ai sw=4" and ":set number" (and some other cmd) commands each time when I open any file in VIM.

For every new instance of VIM I have to enter set of commands. Is there any way where I can put these commands and VIM will execute it every time while opening any file like default settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanent syntax on switch for Vim over OS X Terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405149/permanent-syntax-on-switch-for-vim-over-os-x-terminal)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just paste those lines on the file `~/.vimrc` and they'll be executed everytime VIM is openned. If it does not exist, create one.

Two recommendations:

1. Use a plugin that will auto-load `.vimrc` when you save it. Being confortable with editting `.vimrc` is very important. Building it up with your preferences and key-mappings as you learn VIM is one of the reasons it is so powerful.
2. Google now for some ready `.vimrc` setups as they override some not-so-optimal VIM configurations. For example, you probably won't want that annoying bell beep, among many other things.

Comment: Thank you @Dokkat , created the file and working for line numbers, will explore for ready configurations.

Comment: You don't need (want?) the colons though at the beginning of each line.  Also a "plugin" to autoload your .vimrc when you save it should be as easy as `autocmd BufWritePost *vimrc source <afile>`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `.vimrc` file.

You should create it in your home directory.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. created the file and got that thing in place. !